# CSS Animations - ease-in-out on appearing and disappearing

Tags: html, css, easeinout

For the love of god! I have spent hours trying to figure this out, and nothing seems to work. Please, much help is needed.

So i have managed to write a menu burger (and i dont know how, it's the only component i managed to assign animations too). And on clicking on the burger menu some other links appear and i want it to ease-in/slide-in when appearing on click and out when disappearing on click. Same goes with the searchbar that appears on clicking the '**DISCOVER**' link. I surrender!!

```js
const menuBtn = document.querySelector('.menu-btn');
const menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
let menuOpen = false;
menuBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (!menuOpen) {
    menuBtn.classList.add('open');
    menu.classList.add('open');
    menuOpen = true;
  } else {
    menuBtn.classList.remove('open');
    menu.classList.remove('open');
    menuOpen = false;
  }
});


const discoverLink = document.querySelector('.menuItem:first-child');
const searchbar = document.querySelector('.searchbar');
let searchOpen = false;

discoverLink.addEventListener('click', () => {

  if (!searchOpen) {
    searchbar.classList.toggle('open');
    searchbar.classList.add('open');
    searchOpen = true;
  } else {
    searchbar.classList.remove('open');
    searchOpen = false;
  }
});
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat-Light';
  src: url(fonts\Montserrat-Light.ttf) format(ttf);
}

body {
  background: #272727;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 10vh;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.menu-btn {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  /* border: 3px solid #fff; */
}

.menu-btn__burger {
  width: 30px;
  height: 4px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(255, 101, 47, .2);
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.menu-btn__burger::before,
.menu-btn__burger::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 4px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(255, 101, 47, .2);
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}


/*desloca 1 faixa para cima e outra para baixo */

.menu-btn__burger::before {
  transform: translateY(-6px);
}

.menu-btn__burger::after {
  transform: translateY(6px);
}


/* ANIMATION */

.menu-btn.open .menu-btn__burger {
  transform: translateX(-32px);
  background: transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.menu-btn.open .menu-btn__burger::before {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(35px, -35px);
}

.menu-btn.open .menu-btn__burger::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(35px, 35px);
}

.menu {
  display: none;
  /* hide the menu by default */
}

.menu-btn.open+.menu {
  display: inline-block;
  /* display the menu when the button is clicked */
}

.menu-links {
  position: relative;
  left: 100px;
  top: 3px;
}

.menu-links a {
  text-decoration: none;
  /* remove the underline */
  font: 12px Montserrat-Light, sans-serif;
  color: lightgray;
}

.menu__item {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.navShowed {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  width: 280px;
  right: 10px;
  margin-top: auto;
}

.menuItem {
  font: 12px Montserrat-Light, sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: lightgray;
}

.discover-link {
  position: relative;
}

.searchbar {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  right: 300px;
  top: 38%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 15px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.searchbar input[type="text"] {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 20px;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #333;
}

.searchbar.open {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Trying Animations out</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="menu-btn">
    <div class="menu-btn__burger"></div>
  </div>
  <ul class="menu">
    <div class="menu-links">
      <li class="menu__item"><a href="#about">NIKE</a></li>
      <li class="menu__item"><a href="#services">NEW BALLANCE</a></li>
      <li class="menu__item"><a href="#contact">REEBOK</a></li>
      <li class="menu__item"><a href="#contact">ADIDAS</a></li>
      <li class="menu__item"><a href="#contact">ASICS</a></li>
    </div>
  </ul>

  <div class="navShowed">
    <h3 class="menuItem discover-link">DISCOVER</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="searchbar">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search...">
  </div>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: as this is a small example the component's coordinates are not imported, i have all sorted it out on the master file. i just really want to figure out how can i assign those animations as i mentioned. And also lmk if the javascripts are necessary? i dont think so, thank you!

Comment: Please edit the question and use the snippet tool `<>` to load your html and css.  It makes it so much easier to demonstrate your problem and for others to fix it for you.

Comment: @RohitGupta i had no idea that was possible. my bad! thank you so much for pointing that out for me! done!

Comment: I have now upvoted it. I am not fluent with css animations, so I will leave it for someone else to answer.